# Usage of the word dar

Tags: meaning

There is no entry in [DUDEN dictionary](https://www.duden.de) for the word dar. I have found it in this sentence:

> Dazu stellen wir im Folgenden die Zweckbindung der Verarbeitung Ihrer Daten, den Einsatz von Tracking-/Analyse-Tools, den Einsatz von Cookies, Social-Media-Buttons und Diensten Dritter **dar** und klären Sie über Ihre Rechte auf.

Why is the word dar used? What is its meaning?

Comment: btw: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dar_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

German has separable verbs, and *[darstellen](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/darstellen)* is one of them.

> Futur I: Dazu werden wir die Zweckbindung ... **darstellen.**
> Präsens: Dazu **stellen** wir die Zweckbindung ... **dar.**

In *Präsens* (and some other tenses) the verb must be separated, and then the former prefix moves to the very end of the sentence.

The sentence you posted consists of two main clauses, which are connected to each other with the word *"und"* immediately after *"dar".* So, the prefix *"dar"* stands where is has to be: at the very end of the main clause. And also the core of the verb stands where it belongs to: at position 2.

---

**Addendum (Etymology)**

Today the word *dar* can only be found as prefix or postfix in other words:

> darstellen, darlegen, darbieten, darbringen, darreichen, ...
> immerdar

In Middle High German (MHG) it used to be a distinct adverb:

> MGH: dare, dar

Which derived from an Old High German (OHG) adverb

> OHG: thara

(The english word *there* also derived from this root)
Both, the OHG and the MHG word are also the origin of the German adverb *da,* but also the demonstrative pronoun *der* (*»Was weiß denn der?«*) and the relative pronoun *der* (*»Wehe dem, der mich schlug!«*) are related to these words.

The meaning of *dar* was: "up to a certain point, up to a certain time"

Comment: What is the origin of this prefix? Is it related to "da"?

Comment: Most separable prefixes exist as separate words as well, usually as prepositions, making *dar* a rare exception. The main takeaway is to always check the end of the clause for possible separated prefixes before looking up the verb in the dictionary.

Comment: I would have thought the demonstrative and relative pronouns to be derivations from the definite article "der" (especially since I can as well do your examples with "die"). I would be surprised if they're not related to it. But if they are, does that mean the article derives from the same oprigin, too? And would that also hold for the English "the"?